# pymssql can't connect in a Django view

Tags: python, sql-server, django, pymssql

I'm trying to get a connection to a SQL Server going in one of my views in Django. But I'm getting a wierd problem: It gets stuck as soon I open the connection. My code:

```
import pymssql, json

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from core.helpers import render_json

def get_results_mssql(q):
    conn = pymssql.connect(
        server='...',
        user='...',
        password='...',
        database='...',
        port=1433
    )

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(q)

    result = json.dumps({'data':'done'})
    cursor.close()

    return result

def test_query(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q', None)

    if not q:
        raise Http404

    return render_json(get_results_mssql(q))
```

When I run get_results_mssql from the shell it works. When I do it via a web request using the test_query view it raises the problem. I don't even know where to search for what the problem might be. Any suggestions?

Comment: What versions of Python, Django, pymssql are you using and which OS? What's the error?

Comment: No error. It just stuck.

Comment: I had this too, adding WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to your apache virtualhost fixed it.   See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841663/django-app-hangs-when-attempting-to-connect-to-database-via-apache?rq=1